# The returning light beam that is perpendicular to Earth’s motion

Tags: special-relativity

How did Michelson and Morley compensate for the fact that the returning light beam that is perpendicular to Earth’s motion would not arrive at the same point that it left the half-silvered mirror?

[image]

The Earth is traveling in the direction of the M2 mirror. The light from the half-silvered mirror that hits mirror M1 is not going to return to the half-silvered mirror at exactly the same point since light is independent of the motion of its source.

How is this compensated for? Does this make any real difference?

Comment: Can you describe what you think the effect of "not compensating" would be?

Comment: The animated GIFs in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment#Light_path_analysis_and_consequences) seem to illustrate this quite well.

Answer (score 1):

In the MM experiment, it does not actually matter whether the light beams are exactly perpendicular: what matters is that the light traveling along one "leg" would experience the ether drag head-on, while the other would experience it from the side. As the table rotates, the effect of the ether (if it exists) would shift from one arm to the other, and would result in a shift in the fringes.

In the frame of reference of the experiment, light travels in straight lines, and when reflected from a mirror that is perpendicular to the beam, will come back in the direction it came from.

A stationary observer might see that the light is coming in at an angle, and that the resulting beam is therefore describing a "V". But the beam splitter is moving at the same speed as the rest of the experiment, and therefore the beam arrives, in the lab frame, at the point that it came from.

No adjustment needed to be made.